# Download Video from YouTube in iphone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In one Application i use YouTube Video for display i want first that video download from YouTube then it play from locally from downloaded source.

This is Possible.....If yes then provide suggestion...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PSYouTubeExtractor.h class
It can get youtube mp4 video url and than downloading and viewing is not a problem

Here is my example
https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video

Comment: generating extractors for each video _______
PSYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[PSYouTubeExtractor alloc] init];

Comment: Dynamically creating notifications _______
NSString *notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ID];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleYTVideoDownload:) name:notification object:nil];

Comment: Passing url with notification after downloading _______ 
[extractor getVideoUrlForUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:youtubeLink] notificatoinName:notification];

Comment: @comonitos thanx i have used that it is working after the change of youtube link

Comment: @JaspreetSingh hello ...sir help me how to use PSYouTubeExtractor in projects ...i want to download video from youtube .from sahil bajaj mohali (same loc )..:)

Comment: downloading is not possible for now. but you can save link to stream and open it in MPMovieplayerContoller each time

Comment: @Bajaj please check these link:https://github.com/iosdeveloper/MyTube/downloads
https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video
https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video/downloads

Answer (score 1):

You have to download your video through file location url using NSURLConnection .After that you can MPMovieplayerContoller to run that video.you can google to get example for NSURLConnection and MPMovieplayerController.